# PHP to delete data from csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I read a csv or txt file using fopen method and the file contains 1000s of record , i want to process only the limited record , that means ignore some lines from the start ,

Example: 500 lines with a file means , i will have a search criteria such as "OrderID:12345" this might be in any column of 25th record row , so i need to remove the first 25 records from the file and process the other records

```
while(!feof($file)) {
            $linearray = fgetcsv($file,0,$fieldseparator);
}
```

Comment: while you searching each of line, why do you want to remove records from csv, process only that records which you want to process.

Comment: its a cron job runing on server

Comment: I don't fully understand: do you want to remove n first records from file or find a record by certain criteria?

Comment: salam niyaz, please provide some more explanation about the structure

Comment: so you want to create another csv file, by removing few lines of original file? If not you can simply ignore lines which you dont want to process.

Comment: if i have 500 records means i need to remove the first n records if nth record contains particular matching phrase . the matching phrase will be unique , it may be there or may not , but if the file contains a matcing phrase on any line then it should remove the records untill that line

Comment: so in that case you have to create new file.

Comment: Well, what should be the outcome? Those first n lines should be physically deleted in the CSV file? The remaining lines should be further processed while leaving the file intact? A new file should be created with the remaining lines?

Comment: the outcome would be the record after nth line , 0 to n are removed and the remaining we gonna process , to find nth line we have a matching phrase